# Cant update perticular field in a table with condition using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I cant update  perticular field  in a table with condition.My controller is sitecontroller.php.Anybody help me

Sitecontroler.php

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller
  {
 public function actiondelete_resume()
   {
    $user_id = 97;   
    $sql = "UPDATE job_profile SET resume = '' WHERE user_id = $user_id";
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $command->execute();
    $this->render('upload_new',array('model' =>$model));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$connection` is not set.
Try this:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
```